# Retrofit dont even try to connect api

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to get data from my local server by retrofit. My Call is null, and in logcat my app dont even try to connect to my server.But, when i try to connect in browser(on smartphone) i getting my json, so I can't find problem. Here's my code

**premissions**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

**URLS**

```
public static final String HOST = "http://192.168.0.103:8080/";
public static final String RESIPES = "recipes";
```

**RetrofitClient**

```
private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Urls.HOST)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }


    public static ApiService getApiService(){
        return getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);

    }
```

**ApiService**

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET(Urls.RESIPES)
    Call<List<RecipeDTO>> getData();

}
```

**That how i use retrofit**

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Проверка на соеденение с интернетом

            if(InternetConnection.checkConnection(context)){
                final ProgressDialog dialog;

                //Диалог с пользователем

                dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.gettin_Gson_dialog_title));
                dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.gettin_Gson_dialog_message));
                dialog.show();

                //Создаем объект нашего апи
                ApiService api = RetrofitClient.getApiService();

                //Вызываем джесон
                Call<List<RecipeDTO>> call = api.getData();

                // кол бэк будет вызван как только получит ответ
                call.enqueue(new Callback<List<RecipeDTO>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<RecipeDTO>> call, Response<List<RecipeDTO>> response) {
                        //Dismiss Dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {


                            recipeList.addAll(response.body());


                            adapterRecipes = new RecipesAdapter(context, recipeList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecipes);
                            adapterRecipes.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } else {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, R.string.something_wrong, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<RecipeDTO>> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, R.string.something_wrong, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }});
```

**Model**

public class RecipeDTO {

```
@SerializedName("idRecipe")
@Expose
private long idRecipe;

@SerializedName("nameRecipe")
@Expose
private String nameRecipe;

@SerializedName("category")
@Expose
private CategoryDTO category;

@SerializedName("descriptionRecipe")
@Expose
private String descriptionRecipe;

@SerializedName("tutorialRecipe")
@Expose
private String tutorialRecipe;

@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private byte[] image;

@SerializedName("ingridientRecipe")
@Expose
private List<IngredientDTO> ingridientRecipe;


public RecipeDTO(){

    }

//getters setters
```

Here's this project on github, if i miss smth.

https://github.com/xdewnik/StackQuestion branch retrofit implements

and here's server if someone needs https://github.com/xdewnik/CookingServer

Comment: where is the data model class for RecipeDTO?

Comment: @AalapPatel added

Comment: So if you dont get any error on retrofit call and the response is successful using response.isSuccessful method, u need to check the JSON fields of your response and the model class references you have given to the fields.

Comment: response.isSuccessful  isn't successful, but i dont have error

Comment: if its not successful that mean u have internal server error, u need to print in logs response.errorbody().string()... and observe what is the error

Comment: @IlyaKulikov are you trying this in your emulator?

Comment: @joao86 no, on phone

Comment: Then I suggest you do what Aalap Patel told to do. The server must be sending some information about the issue

Comment: Guys, thanks for help. I don't know what did i do, but i works, all i added is the line ` JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());` ,and i toast this object and it works....

Answer (score 0):

your code seems ok, please set breakpoints before/after the connection check and in the callback success/failure methods and make sure they are reached. Also note that retrofit 2 will not log anything by default, you have to add a HttpLoggingInterceptor for it to do so.
The problem might be as simple as you forgetting to assign the click listener to your view(I couldn't find this code in the github repos you posted)